# Inserting value of checkbox into MySQL column with same name as checkbox name

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Thank you for your responses!  I see where you're coming from.  I didn't word my question as I should have but what I'm really trying to figure out is what is the best way to insert values into the database.

here is an example of the form

```
<form name="election" action="post.php" method="POST">
<b>Sally</b><br><input type="checkbox" name="FR01" value="ON">
<b>Suzy</b><br><input type="checkbox" name="FR02" value="ON">
<b>Jeremy</b><br><input type="checkbox" name="FR03" value="ON">
<b>William</b><br><input type="checkbox" name="FR04" value="ON">
<div id="search" align=center><input type="submit" id="search" value="Cast Vote"></div>
</form>
```

I have a database with election results that has an auto increment ID and then I would like to place "On" into columns that are named after the checkbox, so if checkbox FR01 is checked, insert "On" in that column and they can select up to three candidates.  My confusion is that all the tutorials and examples I look up, no one has a similar situation as I find myself in and therefor I have not found any examples because every example I find, people use the same name and different values.  I want to simply insert on into a column in a table that the same as the checkbox name.

Sorry for the confusion. I am a novice and this is my first time using this website.
Thanks

Comment: Radio buttons all have the same name because only one of them can be checked at a time.  With checkboxes, any amount can be checked, so you'd need some way to detect which are and which aren't.  You can name them all `yourField[]`, and then use a unique ID as the `value`.  That way, you'd have an array of values in your `$_POST['yourField']`, and you'd know which were checked.

Comment: @RocketHazmat  I understand that, sorry for the bad question.

Comment: You can do it any way you want. `name="vote[]" value="candidate1` or `name="candidate1" value="ON"` will both work. But I would not use "ON" as the value stored in the database. A `bool` value (1 or 0) is normally used for that.

Answer (score 2):

Check box can have same name or value. It really depend on the situation or requirement.
See this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Car">I have a car
```

Here name is same that is `vehicle` but value's are different.

And this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myVehicle[]" value="car">I have a car<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="otherVehicle[]" value="car">He has a car
```

Here value is same that is `car` but name's are different.

An array of checkboxes would be most appropriate. By using [] in the checkbox names, PHP will automatically parse them into a native array.

```
$selectedVehicle  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['vehicle']) && is_array($_POST['vehicle']) && count($_POST['vehicle']) > 0){
$selectedVehicle = implode(', ', $_POST['vehicle']);
}

$body .= 'Selected Vehicle: ' . $selectedVehicle;
```

Comment: This is correct, but it PHP it is usually helpful to put square brackets after the name to make it an array (`vehicle[]`).

Comment: Your sample would be even better if you shoed the results in $_POST array.

Comment: Sorry I edited my question because I asked it completely backwards, but the problem I am trying to resolve is posted a bit more clearly now.  Thanks for the great example.